# How to override bower_component main property on bower install?

Tags: gruntjs, bower

I'm using a grunt plugin called bower-concat.  This plugin takes all your bower_component packages and concatenates them into a single file.  It does this by looking at each component's bower.json file's "main" attribute.  I'd like to modify my font-awesome's bower.json "main" attribute from

```
{
  "name": "font-awesome",
  "description": "Font Awesome",
  ...,
  "main": [
    "less/font-awesome.less",
    "scss/font-awesome.scss"
  ]
...
}
```

to this, which allows my grunt-bower-concat plugin to work.

```
{
  "name": "font-awesome",
  "description": "Font Awesome",
  ...,
  "main": [
    "./css/font-awesome.css",
    "./fonts/*"
  ]
...
}
```

By following this post here (https://roots.io/using-bootstrap-with-bower-how-to-override-bower-packages/), I thought I'd be able to override this attribute like so in my app's bower.json file to achieve the desired result upon bower install ...

```
{
  "name": "MyApp"
  "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "~4.4.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "font-awesome": {
      "main": [
        "./css/font-awesome.css",
        "./fonts/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to override font-awesome's "main" attribute.  Can anyone point out what I'm missing?